# Terminate hosting and SSL and redirecting domain name

Tags: ssl, redirect, dns, web-hosting

I have the following scenario:

A website with the domain name **example-old.com** is hosted on a hosting provider.
A website with the domain name **example-new.com** is hosted on another hosting provider.

The owner of the website with domain name **example-old.com** wants to stop **hosting** and **SSL** (to reach the old website you had to type https://example-old.com). He wants to keep the domain name **example-old.com** and when someone navigates to https://example-old.com or http://example-old.com to redirect to https://example-new.com/service.

It goes without saying that hosting and SSL is purchased and used for example-new.com!

I understand that we must somehow use 301 permanent redirect from example-old.com to example-new.com/**service**.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use redirection on a domain without been hosted? I usually do 301 redirects within the **.htaccess** file of my hosting.
2. How do we perform a 301 redirect on the domain name registrar?
3. Provided that we achieved the 301 redirection and since the SSL for the domain example-old.com is no longer paid/valid how is going to react when someone navigates to http**s**://example-old.com? Is it going to fail? Is there a solution to this?
4. To redirect both SSL and non-SSL traffic from example-old.com do I need 2 different redirection rules?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use redirection on a domain without been hosted? I usually do 301 redirects within the .htaccess file of my hosting.

No. If there is no server reachable under the URL then there is no server to issue the redirect.

> How do we perform a 301 redirect on the domain name registrar?

Some registrars offer HTTP redirect in that they host a server by their own for such parked domains. Maybe you could also a CDN like Cloudflare and [add the necessary redirection rules there](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules).

> Provided that we achieved the 301 redirection and since the SSL for the domain example-old.com is no longer paid/valid how is going to react when someone navigates to `https://example-old.com`? Is it going to fail? Is there a solution to this?

To have a redirect from `https://example-old.com` you need to have a valid certificate for `example-old.com` installed on the server issuing the redirect.

> To redirect both SSL and non-SSL traffic from example-old.com do I need 2 different redirection rules?

This depends on the setup and configuration interface for the server issuing the redirect.